# Can anonymous delegate have return value as non void type?

Tags: c#, .net

Can anonymous delegate have return value as non void type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Both the `delegate { return xyz; }` and lambda `x => x+1` syntax can return values.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this question, and wrote a test program. The answer is yes.

```
using System;

public delegate int ReturnedDelegate(string s);

class AnonymousDelegate
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ReturnedDelegate len = delegate(string s)
        {
            return s.Length;
        };
        Console.WriteLine(len("hello world"));
    }
}
```